# Shabbos morning amidah - wrong biblical text - what to do?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, mistakes

Do the works of halacha say what to do if in the Shabbos morning amidah after:

> יִשמַח משֶׁה בְּמַתְּנַת חֶלְקוֹ. כִּי עֶבֶד נֶאֱמָן קָרָאתָ
>   לּוֹ.כְּלִיל תִּפְאֶרֶת בְּראשׁוֹ נָתַתָּ. בְּעָמְדוֹ לְפָנֶיךָ עַל
>   הַר סִינַי. וּשְׁנֵי לֻחוֹת אֲבָנִים הוֹרִיד בְּיָדוֹ. וְכָתוּב בָּהֶם
>   שְׁמִירַת שַׁבָּת וְכֵן כָּתוּב בְּתוֹרָתֶךָ:

instead of saying

> וְשָׁמְרוּ בְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל אֶת הַשַּׁבָּת לַעֲשׂוֹת אֶת הַשַּׁבָּת
>   לְדֹרֹתָם בְּרִית עוֹלָם

a person said

> שָׁמ֣֛וֹר אֶת־י֥וֹם֩ הַשַׁבָּ֖֨ת לְקַדְּשׁ֑֜וֹ כַּאֲשֶׁ֥ר צִוְּךָ֖֣ 
>   ה׳ אֱלֹקיךָ

and then continued normally?

related: [Shabbos Shacharis Shemoneh Esrei: Why V'shamru?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79989/shabbos-shacharis-shemoneh-esrei-why-vshamru)

Comment: The berachot are valuable even if psukim in the middle are changed by svara

Comment: If you haven't yet continued normally, just say ונאמר and say the regular verses too.

Answer (score 7):

While not precisely the same case, I believe this is included in this halacha (O.C. 268:6):

> הטועה בתפל' שבת והחליף של זו בזו אינו חוזר
>
> One who makes a mistake in the Shabbos prayers and switches one for the other (e.g. shacharis for mincha), he does not go back.

The Mishna Brura there (14) explains:

> (יד) אינו חוזר - שעיקר ברכה רביעית היא רצה במנוחתנו וזה נאמר בכל הברכות של שבת ודוקא כשסיים הברכה אבל אם נזכר באמצע ברכה פוסק:
>
> He does not go back: because the main part of the fourth beracha is רצה במנוחתינו, and this is said in all of the versions of the Shabbos prayers.
>
> This is specificly when he finished the beracha, but if he remembered in the middle of the beracha he should stop (and go back).

Even though the pasuk in the question is not in one of the other versions of the beracha, one does not go back (after finishing the beracha), since this is before רצה.